# Value is not a sequence Safari exception

Tags: javascript, safari, polymer

[image]

I'm getting this error on any console.log statement in my codebase. This affects only Safari 11.0 (12604.1.38.1.7) on Mac 10.16.6

How can i resolve this and how this happened?

Comment: I'm not getting this problem, could you paste the console.log you're trying to run

Comment: @pfg it repros only on our running web app. u can try i here https://dev-agendaonline2.appspot.com/ (no need to login)

Comment: this have to be somehow affected by third party libraries. what is the output of `console.log(console.log);`  ( I don't have mac so i can't try)

Comment: @KubaŠimonovský the output is the same: value is not a sequence...

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You need to disable the "WebDriver" extension.

I had this same problem, and my stack trace included a resource called "Script element" which was making this call:

```
b.initMessageEvent("safaridriver.message", !1, !1, a, window.location.origin, "0", window, null);
```

Maybe there's a SafariDriver update out there that also fixes this?

Comment: Saved me a lot of time, thank you! I encountered the issue while testing on Safari 11 on BrowserStack. It wasn't obviously pointing to console.log, but removing console output removed the issue also. To disable the ext; in Safari, Preferences->extensions tab, and uncheck WebDriver extension.

Comment: Nice, I'm glad I have come to this answer :)

Comment: Took me some time to find this but you really saved me, thanks!

Comment: is there any other way to do this. My web app is not workign at all untill i disable to webdriver extension. What can be reason for this?

Answer (score 3):

The main answer here, led me down the wrong path.

Some notes:

- My console.log works just fine in Safari 12.0.3 with no issues what so ever
- The original error of "Value is not a sequence" can be encountered for several different reasons
- I found I was getting the error because my self.postMessage() had two arguments instead of one

  - TypeScript thinks self.postMessage() is supposed to have two arguments
  - Safari threw error because my second postMessage argument was null

My code was:

```
self.postMessage(data,null)
```

Now my working code is:

```
const selfie: Worker = self as any;

selfie.postMessage(data)
```

I find my answer to be relevant because others will use TypeScript and think self.postMessage() needs to have two arguments... And then Safari will break if the second argument is null like several online articles recommend to use.

Comment: Another workaround is to pass undefined instead of null, i.e. `self.postMessage(data, undefined)` which fakes-out the absence of the second parameter, and prevents it from barfing.