# Selenium WebDriver Safari (11.0) TypeError: Value is not a sequence

Tags: java, selenium, safari, browserstack

I'm trying to automate some regression tests for a site using Selenium but get the below console errors in Safari 11.0 whenever the WebDriver extension is active (not there when disabled):
TypeError: Value is not a sequence
TypeError: Not enough arguments

Looks like the same issue this user was seeing:
[Value is not a sequence Safari exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46913856/value-is-not-a-sequence-safari-exception)
But in my case I need the extension in order to run my test build.
(Right? Or can I somehow disable it and still run automated tests?)

I use BrowserStack for my test browsers (I can see the TypeErrors by using their "Live" environment and opening the dev tools there) but need a way to test the site in "Automate" without the extension breaking the sections I'm trying to test.

When I execute my actual automated test I get the error "Expected condition failed: waiting for presence of element" because the needed section of the site entirely fails to load. The test works in other browsers and even older versions of Safari.

I'm new to Selenium and Java so any suggestions on how to get this test running in Safari 11.0 would be greatly appreciated.

My automated test uses Java (Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 9.0.1+11), Selenium 3.7.1 and Eclipse.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Safari provides native support for the WebDriver API starting Safari 10. Source: https://webkit.org/blog/6900/webdriver-support-in-safari-10/. Safari 11 uses the same native Safari toolkit for supporting automation using Selenium and no longer needs the WebDriver extension. This option can be enabled for Safari 11 from **Develop > Allow Remote Automation**.

The errors you highlighted are due to the WebDriver extension and it should be removed/disabled when running Selenium tests on Safari 11. You should connect with their support team and check if they provide an additional capability to disable this.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. BrowserStack support got back to me - they're working on a fix for the bug on their end. I'll update this post with instructions or settings if they provide any but it sounds like no action will be required.

Comment: @abbie -- did this end up being correct? Did BrowerStack fix this on their end?

Comment: I believe they did